# python pandas apply not accepting numpy.float64 args

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, apply, series

I am experiencing issues passing `numpy.float64` variables as arguments to `pandas.Series.apply()`. Is there any way to forcefully use pandas version of the `.mean()` and `.std()` functions to hopefully satisfy Pandas?

**The Code**

```
def normalization(val_to_norm, col_mean, col_sd):
    return (val_to_norm - col_mean) / col_sd

voting_df['pop_estimate'].info()

pop_mean, pop_sd = voting_df['pop_estimate'].mean(), voting_df['pop_estimate'].std()

voting_df['pop_estimate'] = voting_df['pop_estimate'].apply(normalization, pop_mean, pop_sd)
```

**output**

The key line is at the bottom.

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
Int64Index: 3145 entries, 0 to 3144
Series name: pop_estimate
Non-Null Count  Dtype  
--------------  -----  
3145 non-null   float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 49.1 KB

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [46], line 7
      4 voting_df['pop_estimate'].info()
      6 pop_mean, pop_sd = voting_df['pop_estimate'].mean(), voting_df['pop_estimate'].std()
----> 7 voting_df['pop_estimate'] = voting_df['pop_estimate'].apply(normalization, pop_mean, pop_sd)

File c:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:4774, in Series.apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwargs)
   4664 def apply(
   4665     self,
   4666     func: AggFuncType,
   (...)
   4669     **kwargs,
   4670 ) -> DataFrame | Series:
   4671     """
   4672     Invoke function on values of Series.
   4673 
   (...)
   4772     dtype: float64
   4773     """
-> 4774     return SeriesApply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, kwargs).apply()

File c:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:1100, in SeriesApply.apply(self)
   1097     return self.apply_str()
   1099 # self.f is Callable
-> 1100 return self.apply_standard()

File c:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:1151, in SeriesApply.apply_standard(self)
   1149     else:
   1150         values = obj.astype(object)._values
-> 1151         mapped = lib.map_infer(
   1152             values,
   1153             f,
   1154             convert=self.convert_dtype,
   1155         )
   1157 if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], ABCSeries):
   1158     # GH#43986 Need to do list(mapped) in order to get treated as nested
   1159     #  See also GH#25959 regarding EA support
   1160     return obj._constructor_expanddim(list(mapped), index=obj.index)

File c:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\lib.pyx:2919, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

File c:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:139, in Apply.__init__.<locals>.f(x)
    138 def f(x):
--> 139     return func(x, *args, **kwargs)

TypeError: Value after * must be an iterable, not numpy.float64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide additional arguments to a function called with [`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas-series-apply), you need to pass them as keyword arguments, or using a tuple keyword argument `args`.

From the docs:

> **`Series.apply`*****`(func, convert_dtype=True, args=(), **kwargs)`***
>
> Invoke function on values of Series.
>
> Can be ufunc (a NumPy function that applies to the entire Series) or a Python function that only works on single values.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> **func:** *function*
> Python function or NumPy ufunc to apply.
>
> **convert_dtype**: *bool, default True*
> Try to find better dtype for elementwise function results. If False, leave as dtype=object. Note that the dtype is always preserved for some extension array dtypes, such as Categorical.
>
> **args**: *tuple*
> Positional arguments passed to func after the series value.
>
> ****kwargs**
> Additional keyword arguments passed to func.

So to call this with positional arguments:

```py
voting_df['pop_estimate'].apply(normalization, args=(pop_mean, pop_sd))
```

Alternatively, with keyword arguments:

```py
voting_df['pop_estimate'].apply(normalization, col_mean=pop_mean, col_sd=pop_sd)
```

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with data type. You are passing `pop_mean` and `pop_sd` as positional argument and it is used by `apply` not `normalization`.

In order to pass to `normalization` use `args` or keyword arguments:

```
# sample data setup
voting_df = pd.DataFrame({"pop_estimate": range(3144)})

def normalization(val_to_norm, col_mean, col_sd):
    return (val_to_norm - col_mean) / col_sd

pop_mean, pop_sd = voting_df['pop_estimate'].mean(), voting_df['pop_estimate'].std()
```

Method 1: Use `args`:

```
method1 = voting_df['pop_estimate'].apply(normalization, args=(pop_mean, pop_sd))
```

Method 2: Use keyword arguments:

```
method2 = voting_df['pop_estimate'].apply(normalization,  
                                          col_mean=pop_mean, 
                                          col_sd=pop_sd)
```

Besides, in your case, you don't need `apply`. Instead, directly use `normalization`:

```
method3 = normalization(voting_df["pop_estimate"], pop_mean, pop_sd)
```

Or even better, use already well built libraries. For example, `scipy.stats.zscore`:

```
from scipy.stats import zscore

method4 = zscore(voting_df["pop_estimate"], ddof=1)
```

Validation:

```
import numpy as np

np.all([
    np.array_equal(method1, method2),
    np.array_equal(method2, method3),
    np.array_equal(method3, method4)    
])
# True
```